# Android App Map center when touchs a marker

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, google-maps-android-api-2

When I touch a marker on map fragment (v.2), the map is centralized on the touched marker position. How can I drop this behavior? Is it possible? I'd like to keep the title being presented, but with no centralization.

Thanks a lot,

Julio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events):

> You can use an OnMarkerClickListener to listen for click events on the
>   marker. To set this listener on the map, call
>   GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(OnMarkerClickListener). When a user
>   clicks on a marker, onMarkerClick(Marker) will be called and the
>   marker will be passed through as an argument. This method returns a
>   boolean that indicates whether you have consumed the event (i.e., you
>   want to suppress the default behavior). If it returns false, then the
>   default behavior will occur in addition to your custom behavior. The
>   default behavior for a marker click event is to show its info window
>   (if available) and move the camera such that the marker is centered on
>   the map.

This way, you can override the default behavior (center mark+show infowindow) with your custom behavior (show infowindow).
Something like this should work:

On your `OnMarkerClickListener`:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    return true;
}
```